# Please explain the mistake I am making in the piece of code?

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop

Please refer to the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

class ElNinoData(object):
    # Your implementation here 
    # class variables
    add = 0
    count = 0
    average = 0

    # class methods
    def __init__(self , object):
        self.object = object

    def get_humidity():
        return self.object['humidity']

    def conversion():
        self.object = self.object.astype({'zon_winds':'float64','mer_winds':'float64','humidity':'float64','air_temp':'float64','s_s_temp':'float64'})
        return self.object

    def replace_null():
        if not math.isnan(self.object['humidity']):
            global add
            global count
            global average

            add += pd.to_numeric(self.object['humidity'])
            count += 1
            average = add / count
        else:
            self.object['humidity'] = average
        return self.object['humidity']

def get_obj_it():
    lst = ['bouy','day','latitude','longitude','zon_winds','mer_winds','humidity','air_temp','s_s_temp']
    df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\suel.abbasi\\Downloads\\elnino.gz', sep='\s+', header=None)
    df.columns = lst
    df = df.replace({'.':np.nan})

    for i , j in df.iterrows():        
        yield ElNinoData(j)


def average_humidity():    
    e_n_generator = get_obj_it()

    count = 0;
    hum_sum = 0;

    for e_n_row in e_n_generator:
        e_n_row = e_n_row.conversion()
        count += 1
        hum_sum += e_n_row.get_humidity()

    print("Mean Humidity is '{}' Percent".format(hum_sum/count))
average_humidity()
```

The code keeps throwing an error, I cant understand the error. I am trying to implement a class to programatically represent the data entries.

### The error is below is:

***TypeError: conversion() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was***

Comment: conversion() must be defined as conversion(self) inside the class definition. More on class methods declaration: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Please post the traceback that shows the call stack and the exact line with the error. And consider making a smaller example without extraneous code unrelated to the problem. Make it easy for us!

Comment: The python tutorial is a great resource to learn the basics of the language. This talks about classes: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class defined functions, you need to pass self as an argument when defining them. So, instead of `def conversions():`, try `def conversion(self)`. Do the same with get_humidity() and replace_null().